# find pipe to less - why only correct lines are left when I press "up" key?

Tags: bash, find, less

I by accident find a good way to filter useful lines of `find`: just pipe it to `less` and when it shows `(END)` at the bottom, press `up` arrow key and only correct lines are left. No `Permission denied`, no symbolic link errors, nothing else.

```bsh
find / -name foo | less
```

But, why? Cannot find an answer about why this behaviour. `less` magically filters out non-result lines?

Comment: Now of course, `find / -name foo 2>/dev/null` does the same thing, but `less` is useful when the output is long. Well.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`find` with no “action” applies its default `-print` action, which outputs the full file name to standard output. Errors go to standard error.

The pipe operator only redirects standard output; so only “correct” file names are sent to `less`, everything else goes to standard error, which is your terminal. `less` *also* writes to your terminal, so you’ll initially see both file names and errors on your screen; but when you scroll up in `less` (or invoke any other action which causes it to update the screen), the errors will be overwritten by `less`’s updates since `less` is only aware of the input it’s seen from `find`’s standard output.

To page through the complete output in `less`, you need to redirect standard error too:

```
find / -name foo 2>&1 | less
```

To completely ignore errors, redirect it to the bit bucket instead:

```
find / -name foo 2>/dev/null | less
```

Comment: OK but I thought I see these "Permission denied" lines before pressing Up key. Do they belong to stderr?

Comment: Yes, `find` writes them to its standard error. `less`’s output is mixed up with that sent directly to your terminal, until it refreshes the screen (which happens when you scroll up).

Comment: I like to remember this by em-phasing the important part of the word`stderr`: std*err* as in, error :) just a tip in remembering it. @WesternGun

Comment: I think in bash you can simply say `find / -name foo |& less`.

Comment: @Peter indeed! I’ve had enough comments about non-POSIX stuff to avoid those constructs in answers that aren’t explicitly about bash (and the tag isn’t specific enough in my experience).

Comment: Fair enough :-)

Comment: @NordineLotfi, ...though that's a bit misleading, since stderr has more than just errors -- it also is the correct place for _diagnostic output_. Lots of things are "diagnostic" -- status logs, prompts to the user; really, anything that isn't part of the actual _output_ a program is built to generate.

Comment: Indeed. I never explicitly said this was _only_ *always* about error. But I agree what I said could be interpreted as such as you said... @CharlesDuffy

Answer (score 10):

This has nothing to do with `less` itself. It's just that there are two output streams: standard output (`stdout`) and standard error (`stderr`). Error messages, as you would expect, go to `stderr`, while regular output goes to `stdout`. The pipe, by default, only captures `stdout` and ignores `stderr`. Since find's errors are in `stderr`, these are not sent to `less` and this is why it looks like `less` is filtering out the errors.

Comment: Ah yes. `find / -name rime 2>null` gives me the same output in terminal. Good. Now I don't know which answer to accept coz you are equally correct.

Comment: @WesternGun I would go for Stephen's, he gives a bit more detail. But it's completely up to you, whichever one you prefer. I can guarantee that neither Stephen nor I will take it personally :)

Comment: Thanks for being so generous. And correction to my comment: `find / -name rime 2>/dev/null`.